# iOS if statements in tableView:numberOfRowsInSection: not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview

I'm trying to use view tags to determine what view is currently being displayed, but when I use this code

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (self.view.tag != 3){
     NSLog(@"view is not 3");
     return 10;
    }
else{
     NSLog(@"view is 3");
     return 20;
    }
}
```

the correct amount of rows is not set for the view with the tag `3`, although it does work on all my other views. For example, on my view with the `1` tag, `view is not 3` will be logged, but on my view with a tag of `3`, nothing is logged. Anyone know why this isn't working as I want?

Comment: What does `NSLog(@"%d", self.view.tag)` have to say?

Comment: The problem was that I didn't have my delegate and dataSource set up properly.

Comment: my only guess is, your tableview delegate (the viewcontroller where this numberOfRowsInSection method exists) is not set when you are in view3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was a careless mistake by myself, I didn't set up my dataSource and delegate.

Comment: Not the first time this has happened. The SO community requests that you accept your answer for good measure.

Comment: Yea, I just don't get why they make me wait 2 days to accept it.

Comment: ooooh right I forgot about that

Answer (score 0):

self.view is the main `View` for the `ViewController`.  What you probably need to be doing is getting a reference to the TableView.

Change to:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
if (tableView.tag != 3){
     NSLog(@"view is not 3");
     return 10;
    }
else{
     NSLog(@"view is 3");
     return 20;
    }
}
```